# How to count how many times something occures in a loop, java

Tags: java

I am trying to find out how many times the 6 occurs in this loop.
I tried array, `ArrayList`, sapply and others but I still can't make it work.

Here is the code

```
public class Numbersinhere {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int Min = 1;
        int Max = 6;

        for (int y = 0;
             y < 6000;
             y++) {
            int x = Min + (int) (Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1));
            System.out.println(x);
            //how many times the 6 ??????????
        }   
    }
}
```

It throws a dice 6000 times.

I guess I have to use the variable `short`, but nothing behind that works

Maybe its because of `public static void main(String[] args) {` but what else should I use in java?

Comment: *I am trying to find out how many times the 6 occures in this loop.* - can you explain what you mean?

Comment: What exactly is preventing you from comparing `x` with `6` inside the `for` loop to see when a 6 occurs, and then incrementing another variable if you want to keep count of how many times a 6 occurred?

Comment: `if(x==6) count++`

Comment: Take care of java naming conventions. variable names should start with lower case characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this method

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        // your code goes here
        int min = 1;
        int max = 6;
        int reps = 10, x, count = 0;

        for (int y = 0;
             y < reps;
             y++) {
            x = min + (int) (Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1));
            System.out.println(x);
            if(x == 6) {
                count++;
            }
            //how many times the 6 ??????????
        }
        System.out.println("Count = " + count);
    }
```

Comment: @Roswan It's just declaring a variable `count` and incrementing it when a 6 comes.

Comment: like accpeting a defeat